# How to connect 8-bit display to GPIO extender

Tags: circuit-design, gpio, esp32, tft

I wanted to connect an 8-bit resistive touch display to a I2C GPIO extender which get's connected to a ESP-32, as seen in the picture

[image: EasyEDA circuit drawing]

The display has a lot of pins, and I really need to know if I need to connect something else or if everything is connected properly.
I'm new to electronics, so theory and explanations are always welcomed.
Here is a link to the display data sheet:

https://docs.rs-online.com/328f/0900766b816aff38.pdf

Comment: an unconnected reset pin is always something to double check

Comment: the datasheet you linked says nothing about which data pins are used for minimum operation

Comment: Well, the display might have I2C interface already, but the resitive touch interface can't be connected to digital GPIO.

Comment: This interface will be dead slow if it works at all. Try to use the SPI option of the display.

Comment: @Jens thanks for the advice, but can you like explain me a bit more how am I supposed to do it please !!! a simple drawing would be enough

Comment: A search engine found me a *LCD-DT028V1* expansion board showing just the serial interface (+ a few control signal + PS) connected. I'm not ready to assume an external serial-to parallel conversion buys you anything.